# 400 Error while Changing Transition State to Resolved for a JIRA ticket using REST API

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I have one JIRA ticket which follows below workflow to get closed.

New -> In Review -> Work In Progress -> Resolved -> Waiting for Confirmation -> Closed

now, using the transition endpoint, "/rest/api/2/issue/:issue_key/transitions" I'm able to change first two status that is from New to In Review & In Review to Work In Progress but from from Work In Progress to Resolved is not happening, it's throwing 400 error with a error message below.

Response Status : 400 description : {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_26106":"This field is required for this transition","customfield_27906":"This field is required for this transition"}}

Please Note: I've not done any mistake while passing the transition ID, checked multiple times.

Please help me with the solution, why it's not transitioning it's state to work in progress to resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the error self-explanatory? Jira projects can have complex configurations.

It looks like you can't just transition `Work In Progress -> Resolved` without setting some fields in the Jira issue. It's complaining about `customfield_26106` and `customfield_27906` being **required to transition** from one state to another.